# How to add gap between list items using boot strap and make them of equal length

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have following code ,

```
<ul id="lstproducts" class="list-unstyled">
    <li draggable="true"><button class="btn btn-outline btn-danger">Dragabl1</button></li>
    <li draggable="true"><button class="btn btn-outline btn-danger">Drabl1</button></li>
    <li draggable="true"><button class="btn btn-outline btn-danger">D1 </button></li>
    <li draggable="true"><button class="btn btn-outline btn-danger">Drl1 Jumpets Expanda</button></li>
 </ul>
```

And the out put looks like this:

[image]

Now How do I:
1. Make all buttons of same length.
2. Add gap between List Items.

**Update** after adding

```
.list-unstyled li{
  width: 300px; 
  margin-bottom: 5px; 
}
```

I am still getting same result. Checked in chrome developer tools and can see the style sheet applied.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go with Nav pills stacked.

```css
.btn-outline{
width:100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
    <li draggable="true"><button class="btn btn-outline btn-danger">Dragabl1</button></li>
    <li draggable="true"><button class="btn btn-outline btn-danger">Drabl1</button></li>
    <li draggable="true"><button class="btn btn-outline btn-danger">D1 </button></li>
    <li draggable="true"><button class="btn btn-outline btn-danger">Drl1 Jumpets Expanda</button></li>
  </ul>
```

It might not sound right, and may not be intended for this. But this solution requires very less css changes & *most probably* does not affect accessibility.

Comment: This works perfect for me and very much intended results :) , Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by adding some CSS for example:

```
.list-unstyled li{
  width: 300px; 
  margin-bottom: 5px; 
}
```

Comment: Added the style but still it's not working , please check the update .

Comment: Hmmm maybe you could set the width of the buttons inside `li`s to 100%. it's hard to debug from a distance.